# DB::raw is there any way to date_format with language?

Tags: laravel

```
$test = Test::query()
            ->select("test.id as id", "users.first_name as first_name", "users.last_name as last_name")
            ->addSelect("test.company_name as company_name", "test.email as email")
            ->addSelect(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(test.created_at, '%d-%m-%Y') as created"))
            ->join("users", "users.id", "=", "test.user_id")
            ->where("test.test_id", "=", $test->id)
            ->get();
```

It is formating datatable dates but it is not giving language format if i made %b it giving just english lang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

according to [mysql doc](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19078-01/mysql/mysql-refman-5.1/internationalization-localization.html#locale-support):

> Beginning with MySQL 5.1.12, the locale indicated by the lc_time_names
> system variable controls the language used to display day and month
> names and abbreviations. This variable affects the output from the
> DATE_FORMAT(), DAYNAME(), and MONTHNAME() functions.

in your case the code would be:

```
DB::statement("SET lc_time_names = 'ar_BH';"); // or any locale you want, see the supported locales in the same link.
```

then add `-%b`:

```
->addSelect(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(test.created_at, '%d-%m-%Y-%b') as created"))
```